# Wrong Result Calculate value with checkbox use Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Now im doing some Calculate Checkbox Value Using JQuery and PHP code. The mechanism is, when User checked the checkbox, it will sum the price. I implemented a formula for JQuery but the result it not correct. here is my code

JQUERY

```
<script>
$(function() {
      $('.dealprice').on('input', function(){

        const getItemPrice = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[name=itemprice]').val(); 

        var eachPrice = 0;
        $('.dealprice:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
            eachPrice += isNaN(parseInt(getItemPrice)) ? 0 : parseInt(getItemPrice);
        }); 
        $("#totalDeal").text(eachPrice.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
        
    });
 });
    </script>
```

for more detail. i made a sample on this site  https://repl.it/@ferdinandgush/Sum-Calculate-checkbox just click "run" button and you can able to test it. i need to display correct calculate following that table format

Please help.

Comment: Can you please attach you html or create minimum reproduction example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to define getItemPrice inside the loop, otherwise you are calculating it only once for the item that was clicked, instead of doing it for every item.

```js
$(function() {
      $('.dealprice').on('input', function(){
      
        var eachPrice = 0;
        $('.dealprice:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
            const getItemPrice = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[name=itemprice]').val();
            
            eachPrice += isNaN(parseInt(getItemPrice)) ? 0 : parseInt(getItemPrice);
        }); 
        $("#totalDeal").text(eachPrice.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
        
    });
 });
```

```html
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-qh0q">Item</th>
    <th class="tg-qh0q">Price</th>
    <th class="tg-qh0q">Deal</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Book</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">$ 10 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="10"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="checkbox" class="dealprice" name="deal[12][0]"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Pencil</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">$ 5 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="5"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="checkbox" class="dealprice" name="deal[12][1]"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Pen</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">$ 8 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="8"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="checkbox" class="dealprice" name="deal[12][2]"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><span id="totalDeal">0</span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `getItemPrice` inside of the function of where you get its checked. Please check the following code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.dealprice').on('input', function(){
    var eachPrice = 0;
    $('.dealprice:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
      const getItemPrice = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[name=itemprice]').val();
      eachPrice += isNaN(parseInt(getItemPrice)) ? 0 : parseInt(getItemPrice);
    }); 
    $("#totalDeal").text(eachPrice.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
  });
});
```

Also check this repl https://repl.it/repls/LavenderAgonizingRoot